# Binominal distribution: How to calculate Alpha, so that the probability is covered by the confidence interval?

Tags: python, statistics, probability, confidence-interval

So, I have the code, that calculates bounds of confidence interval

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.stats.proportion import proportion_confint   
    
def bin_conf (k, n, a):
    alpha, count, nobs = a, k, n
    return proportion_confint(count, nobs, alpha, method='normal')

bin_conf(75, 300, 0.05)
>>> (0.20100090038649865, 0.29899909961350135)
```

But I need to count the alpha, so that an already defined probability is also covered by an already defined confidence interval ?

For example: Size of trials (n) = 500. Successful trials = 200. CI = [0,35 ; 0,45]. Alpha = ?

Has 'statsmodels' or any other Python library the solution to find out that?

Answer (score 1):

statsmodels does not have a helper function for this because it is not an usual use case.

However, confidence intervals based on normal distribution can be easily inverted. The width of the confidence interval is two times the critical value times the standard deviation of the mean.

```
from scipy import stats

ci = [0.35, 0.45]
count, nobs = 200, 500

p = count / nobs
std = np.sqrt(p * (1 - p) / nobs)
critval = (ci[1] - ci[0]) / std / 2
alpha = stats.norm.sf(critval) * 2  # two-sided
alpha

0.02247887336612522
```

Check that it is the same as the "normal" proportion_confint

```
proportion_confint(count, nobs, alpha, method='normal')
(0.35, 0.45000000000000007)
```

The same could be used for confidence intervals based on the t-distribution, by replacing `stats.norm` by `stats.t` and using appropriate degrees of freedom